# How to look for a string within the contents of each file on a list? -Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following line which gives me a list of files.

```
{Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force $filePath | sort-object -property CreationTime -descending | where { $_.CreationTime.dayofyear -eq $today } | Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and ( $_.Name -like "*FILE1*" -or $_.Name -like "*FILE2*" -or $_.Name -like "*FILE3*") } | Select-Object Name,CreationTime,CreationDay | Format-Table -AutoSize * }
```

Here's my results:

**Name             CreationTime**

- FILE1.022291   8/25/2016 8:25:07 AM
- FILE2.022285   8/25/2016 2:25:10 AM
- FILE3.022281   8/25/2016 2:25:08 AM

I'd like to look for two specific strings within each file of the results, and if any of the specific strings are found, display the whole line that the string is on below each result.

Here's what I'm hoping it can look like

**Name         CreationTime**

- FILE1.022291 8/25/2016 8:25:07 AM

  - THIS_IS_ALL_OF_LINE_4_WITH_SPECIFICSTRING1
- FILE2.022285 8/25/2016 2:25:10 AM

  - THIS_IS_ALL_OF_LINE_16_WITH_SPECIFICSTRING2
- FILE3.022281 8/25/2016 2:25:08 AM

  - THIS_IS_ALL_OF_LINE_7_WITH_SPECIFICSTRING1

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm somewhat new to Powershell so I'll do my best to help with any questions.

Comment: Which version of PowerShell are you using (check `$PSVersionTable`)

Comment: PSVersion                      5.1.14393.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Select-String for that info. Just get the file objects filter for the date you are looking for, then use Select-String. Select-String's out is FileName:LineNumber:Match.

```
PS> gci -File -Path $filePath file* | ? creationtime -gt (get-date).AddMinutes(-30) | Select-String -Pattern "SpecificString1|SpecificString2"

FILE1.022291:2:SpecificString1
FILE2.022285:4:SpecificString2
FILE3.022281:1:SpecificString1
```

And here is some formatting using named expressions in the select statement.

```
PS> gci -File -Path $filePath file* | ? creationtime -gt (get-date).AddMinutes(-30) | Select @{n='StringFound';e={$_ | Select-String -Pattern "SpecificString1|SpecificString2"}}, CreationTime;

StringFound                            CreationTime
-----------                            ------------
C:\temp\FILE1.022291:2:SpecificString1 8/25/2016 1:09:50 PM
C:\temp\FILE2.022285:4:SpecificString2 8/25/2016 1:09:50 PM
C:\temp\FILE3.022281:1:SpecificString1 8/25/2016 1:09:50 PM
```

Here is working with the select-string output:

```
 PS> gci -File -Path $filePath file* | ? creationtime -gt (get-date).AddMinutes(-600) | Select-String -Pattern "Speci
ficString1|SpecificString2" -AllMatches | select LineNumber, FileName, Line, matches

LineNumber Filename     Line                       Matches
---------- --------     ----                       -------
         2 FILE1.022291 SpecificString1            {SpecificString1}
         4 FILE1.022291 sfdgdsgsdf SpecificString2 {SpecificString2}
         6 FILE1.022291 SpecificString2            {SpecificString2}
         4 FILE2.022285 SpecificString2            {SpecificString2}
         1 FILE3.022281 SpecificString1            {SpecificString1}
```

Stringing two select string for a simple negate.

```
PS> gc C:\tmp\test.txt
this is foo
this is foo*bag
this is the bang

PS> gc C:\tmp\test.txt | Select-String -Pattern 'foo' -AllMatches | Select-String -SimpleMatch '*' -NotMatch -AllMatches | fl


IgnoreCase : True
LineNumber : 1
Line       : this is foo
Filename   : InputStream
Path       : InputStream
Pattern    : foo
Context    :
Matches    : {foo}
```

Comment: irThemis, this worked, but I added "-allmatches" to the select-string.  Also, the select string hit multiple times within a few files and the output looks like this:
{C:\temp\FILE1.022310:1:STRINGMATCHED1, C:\temp\FILE1.022310:213:STRINGMATCHED1,C:\temp\FILE1.022310:221:STRINGMATCHED1, C:\tem...
C:\temp\FILE2.022311:1:STRINGMATCHED2...

Can I suppress the path and only show the filenames?  Also, can I show the results as a list?

Comment: Yes select-string -allmatches, kicks back an object, i'll update the post with the statement.

Comment: Mike P, If this helped please mark it as the answer.

Comment: Any time, glad I could help!

Comment: I hope it's OK that I'm re-opening this.  I'm getting the expected results but am looking to exclude files from the results that contain a specific string that contains asterisks.  How would I go about this?

Again, sorry if I'm being greedy.  I hope this can help others in the future.

Comment: sure just select string twice or use a more complex regex, posted the simpler one.